# How to make sorting by date(TimeStamp) in flutter firebase document list?

Tags: firebase, flutter, sorting, google-cloud-firestore

I want to sort flutter firebase list by the last date to old date. in currently, Firebase send mixed list. And  I want to sort them..

I made this code but I get error in firebase

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('CompanyAdvert')
      .where('isVerify', isEqualTo: true).orderBy('createdTime', descending: false)
      .snapshots();
```

**I get this error in console**

*Listen for Query(target=Query(CompanyAdvert where isVerify == true order by createdTime, **name**);
limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/project_one/firestore/indexes?create_composite=ClBwcm9qZWN0cy9jYW4tZ, cause=null}*

Comment: Hi @Zekai Demir, Could please include the error that you're getting. Also, what is the Date/DateTime format of "createdTime"?

Comment: I've tried two format(TimeStamp and String) for createdTime field but I get same error.

Comment: As stated from the error, you have to create an index first by clicking the link provided. You may also refer on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50207339/cloud-firestore-failed-precondition-the-query-requires-an-index) for more information.

Comment: for newbies (me) who are not able to build the index correctly, either could i, so went to firebase project / cloud firestore / indexes, deleted what was there, ran the code, and vs code gave me exact url to biuld the index in the way the code needed it.

Answer (score 0):

open the link on firebase console website and display one Dialog popup for create index.

Just click on Add index button. then refresh the app. It will work :)